# Is there any difference between recovering from HDD or flash memory, SSD?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

Is there any difference between software which are used for recovering data from HDD or flash memory drives and SSD? For example, can we use of the apps used for HDD to recover data from SSD too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you've ever used one of those tools to try and recover data from a Flash Drive, then you can use it on an SSD. SSDs are built the same way Flash Drives are.

Comment: Thank you. For example Recuva is very good for flash drives and also HDD but can it be such good also for SSD?

Comment: Exactly. A Flash Drive is an SSD. Flash Drives ARE EXACTLY Solid State Drives, their memory storage is exactly the same, they are just built differently.

Comment: Thank you. A +1 vote for now and an answer vote if you wait some while :)